# RabbitMQ Java client auto reconnect

Tags: java, rabbitmq

When my application looses connection to RabbitMQ I have its connection factory set to automatically try and reconnect

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setUsername(username);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(1);
    factory.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
    factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    factory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
```

When it is trying to reconnect it blocks but it never stops blocking once it gets connected again and I am not to sure why.

I am using the latest version of the java client 3.3.4

This also seems to happen when I force disconnect the client connection via the rabbitmq management interface.

Some further research it seems like its hanging while it is trying to get a channel but the web interface says there is a channel connected.

Comment: what about your `networkRecoveryInterval` property? Also consider to set the request heartbeet to more than one second in production environment...

Comment: Yup this is just for testing right now. I actually just set the networkRecoveryInterval to 0 and now it is actually throwing an error when it can't reconnect which is a start. However it still seems to hang once it finally reconnects. I managed to do a thread dump and this is the only thing I could find for rabbitmq http://pastebin.com/X8bR8Bgr

Comment: Add an ShutDownListener to get more information: http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.3.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.3.4/com/rabbitmq/client/ShutdownListener.html

By the way rabbitmq has some weird default properties, for example connectionTimeout's default is 0, which means waiting infinitely if.

I am not quite sure about `topologyRecoveryEnabled` can you try it with the default value?

Comment: Well that is strange. Apperently auto recovery doesn't work right if i manually stop rabbitmq gracefully. But if I disconnect from the network it works perfectly fine. That seems rather weird

Comment: When I manually stop rabbitmg I get broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown' from the shutdown listener. But once I turn rabbitmq back on it will reconnect and remake the queues but wont allow anything else

Comment: I am using rabbitmq in a cluster with 3 nodes, so reconnect works fine then. I broke up the connection via an iptables command.

Comment: You might see if running through [Lyra](https://github.com/jhalterman/lyra) solves your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To wrap it all together, here my answer.

First of all rabbitmq, or at least the java client, has some weird default properties which are sometimes in seconds and sometimes in milliseconds. Also their default values do not seem well thought from my point of view. For example `connectionTimeout`s default value is 0, which means wait for ever.

You should also set the `networkRecoveryInterval` property to some usefull value in your environment.

To get a more information what caused the channel to close, implement a [`ShutdownListener`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.3.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.3.4/com/rabbitmq/client/ShutdownListener.html) - Even if it just prints the exception, it will help you to find out what caused the error.

To test auto recovery of a connection I used an ip tables command on the client side. Then you can also see what happens on the server side in the rabbitmq.log

And do not forget to adjust the `requestHeartbeet` property, in my setup its always above 5 seconds, the default one is in some client implementations 580 seconds which seems a bit strange also, keep that in mind.

In any way, even if you run rabbitmq in a cluster, it does not work well on unreliable networks. Maybe you are interested in more regarding this than I should advise you to look in the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html).

Comment: Update: it looks like the later versions (currently 4.1.0) at least sets the connection timeout to 60 seconds by default instead of 0. Thanks for the info.